# custom segue to achieve slide menu from left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, segue

I am new to animation, and trying to write a custom segue to achieve slide out a side menu from left to right, overlay the home view, and occupy half of the screen.

[image: segue from home view to side bar view]

There is a custom segue code:

```
#import "CustomSegue.h"

@implementation CustomSegue

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *contentVC = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *sideBarVC = self.destinationViewController;
    CGRect sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame;
    [sideBarVC.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, contentVC.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGRect animationFrame = contentVC.view.frame;
    sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame;
    animationFrame.size.width = contentVC.view.frame.size.width / 2;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:
     ^{
        sideBarVC.view.frame = animationFrame;
    }
                     completion:
     ^(BOOL finished) {
        sideBarVC.view.frame = animationFrame;
        contentVC.view.alpha = 0.5f;
        [[contentVC.view superview] addSubview:sideBarVC.view];
    }];

}

@end
```

I add some variable to see if the frame is correct, and it is correct when I change the frame.

But I don't see my "expected" animation: sideBarVC.view.frame = animationFrame;

Could some one help on this? Thanks.

Comment: add a break point at UIView animateWithDuration shows animationFrame = CGRect origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=187.5, height=667);          sideFrame = CGRect origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=667);                                         so I can see the sideBarVC.view.frame is CGRect origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=667), but the real animation seems from right to left, not left to right. I don't know why start point x is 0, end point is 187.5 could give the animation from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a slide from left to right animation, you will firstly have to set the original X of animating view's frame to be a negative value, then in the animation block, set original x to be 0. Something like that.

```
sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame;

sideBarVC.view.frame = CGRectOffset(sideFrame, - contentVC.view.frame.size.width, 0);
[[contentVC.view superview] addSubview:sideBarVC.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    sideBarVC.view.frame = sideFrame;
    contentVC.view.alpha = 0.5f;
} completion:nil];
```

Using your code I don't see animation happens, because `sideBarVC.view` is added in the completion block of the animation. By then the animation has already finished, and  `sideBarVC.view` is added as subview and its frame is set.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the position at beginning. but it still has one problem, the side bar menu is under navigation tool bar. Do anyone know how to solve it? See the screen shot (sorry I dont know how to smaller the size)

Comment: You'll want to add the subview to the window like this. `[[[contentVC.view superview] window] addSubview:sideBarVC.view];
`

Comment: sorry to bother again, if I slide out the menu, and add a button on top left of the slide menu to be a 'back' button to home view, what is the proper way to implement the button? not sure how to implement the segue or other techniques.

Comment: My suggestion is the opposite of the current code does, just hide the sideBarVC.view, make it invisible. For the button, you can add a selector for it, do the action there, or wind the button to a custom segue in storyboard, and implement the custom segue class.

Comment: I need the animation as well, so I created a unwind segue. But every time I click the button, it crashes...  wondering what is happening.

Comment: You can ask another question on that. Someone with experience on unwind segue would be able to fix the issue very soon, make sure you have code and crash messages.

Comment: Seems it is a series problem. not trigger anything but click the button will crash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959170/tap-button-cause-app-crash-on-side-bar

Answer (score 0):

Tunred out I misunderstand the position. Using below code could achieve the animation,

but it still has one problem, the side bar menu is under navigation tool bar on top of the screen. Do anyone know how to solve it?

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *contentVC = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *sideBarVC = self.destinationViewController;
    CGRect sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame;
    [sideBarVC.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-(contentVC.view.frame.size.width), 0, contentVC.view.frame.size.width/2, contentVC.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGRect animationFrame = contentVC.view.frame;
    sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame;
    animationFrame.size.width = contentVC.view.frame.size.width / 2;
    sideBarVC.view.alpha = 0;
    [[[contentVC.view superview] window] addSubview:sideBarVC.view]; < -- this is important, not [superview addSubView]
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
        sideBarVC.view.frame = animationFrame;
        sideBarVC.view.alpha = 1;
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        sideBarVC.view.alpha = 1;
        sideBarVC.view.frame = animationFrame;

    }];
```

[image: but it still has one problem, the side bar menu is under navigation tool bar on top of the screen. Do anyone know how to solve it?]

Comment: changed to [[[contentVC.view superview] window] addSubview:sideBarVC.view]; rather than [superview addSubView]

Comment: how do you unwind this segue? ive been trying for a while now and can't seem to get it to work :\

Comment: unwind segue? It is a new segue. If you are talking about the revert animations, just record the new and old frame, and animate it.

Comment: i tried repeating the animation in the reverse but it keeps crashing. I think the problem is that this segue treats the VC that comes into view as a subview rather than a true segue to replace the first VC... maybe lol

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959170/tap-button-cause-app-crash-on-side-bar

Comment: solved the segue dilemma. last question though - did you find yourself having trouble displaying objects in the sideBarVC? even if I constrain it to the center of the view it gets thrown to the top of the view - not sure what's going on

Comment: @WillVonUllrich it sounds like you are using autolayout but you don't add enough conatraints. did you add centerY conatraint

Comment: I restarted xcode and it seemed to work... i fully constrained it now just to be safe lol. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

```
         override func perform() {
            let contentVC = self.sourceViewController;
            let sideBarVC = self.destinationViewController;

            var sideFrame = sideBarVC.view.frame

            sideBarVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: -(contentVC.view.frame.size.width), y: 0, width: contentVC.view.frame.size.width/2, height: contentVC.view.frame.size.height)

            sideFrame = sideFrame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * contentVC.view.frame.size.width, dy: 0)
            contentVC.view.superview?.addSubview(sideBarVC.view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                sideBarVC.view.frame = sideFrame
                contentVC.view.alpha = 0.5
            }
        }
```